# Tomcat count not run Spring websocket and throw error "could not create bean class WebSocketAnnotationMethodMessageHandler"

Tags: spring-websocket

Spring websocket run smooth on Jetty 9.1.1+ 
But run error on Tomcat 7.0.63 and Tomcat 8.0.24

**Tomcat error log**

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could
>   not instantiate bean class
>   [org.springframework.web.socket.messaging.WebSocketAnnotationMethodMessageHandler]:
>   Constructor threw exception; nested exception is
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.springframework.core.convert.converter.ConverterRegistry.addConverter(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/Class;Lorg/springframework/core/convert/converter/Converter;)V
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:141)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:108)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:280)
>     ... 27 more Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.springframework.core.convert.converter.ConverterRegistry.addConverter(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/Class;Lorg/springframework/core/convert/converter/Converter;)V
>     at
>   org.springframework.core.convert.support.DefaultConversionService.addScalarConverters(DefaultConversionService.java:132)
>     at
>   org.springframework.core.convert.support.DefaultConversionService.addDefaultConverters(DefaultConversionService.java:75)
>     at
>   org.springframework.format.support.DefaultFormattingConversionService.(DefaultFormattingConversionService.java:90)
>     at
>   org.springframework.format.support.DefaultFormattingConversionService.(DefaultFormattingConversionService.java:65)
>     at
>   org.springframework.messaging.simp.annotation.support.SimpAnnotationMethodMessageHandler.(SimpAnnotationMethodMessageHandler.java:102)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.socket.messaging.WebSocketAnnotationMethodMessageHandler.(WebSocketAnnotationMethodMessageHandler.java:44)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:126)
>     ... 29 more

**App-config.xml**

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />

<context:annotation-config />

<mvc:resources mapping="/static/**" location="/" />

<context:component-scan base-package="com.websocket.config" />

<websocket:message-broker
    application-destination-prefix="/cqp">
    <websocket:stomp-endpoint path="/connect/sockjs">
        <websocket:sockjs />
    </websocket:stomp-endpoint>
    <websocket:simple-broker prefix="/topic" />
</websocket:message-broker>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.core.convert.converter.ConverterRegistry.addConverter(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/Class;Lorg/springframework/core/convert/converter/Converter;)

Looks like you have there some old `spring-core` jar in the classpath, which is loaded before your own dependencies:

`ConverterRegistry`

```
/**
 * Add a plain converter to this registry.
 * The convertible sourceType/targetType pair is specified explicitly.
 * Allows for a Converter to be reused for multiple distinct pairs without having to create a Converter class for each pair.
 * @since 3.1
 */
void addConverter(Class<?> sourceType, Class<?> targetType, Converter<?, ?> converter);
```

Pay attention to the `@since 3.1`. So you should clean Tomcat classpath from those pre-3.1 Spring jars.

**UPDATE**

Try to use `-verbose:class` for the JVM (Tomcat) run to determine which version and from where the `ConverterRegistry` class is loaded: https://dzone.com/articles/how-use-verbose-options-java

Comment: I used "spring-core-4.2.4.RELEASE", It run ok on Jetty, Error just throw on Tomcat

Comment: See an UPDATE to my answer.

Comment: Yeah ... it work ... I try to use "-verbose:class" and I show me where library conflict ... after that, I just remove conflict version and fix codes.

Comment: Thanks you so much Artem Bilan